# How to fix this crash - Map location update

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I am getting location when application in active state and saving latitude and longitude in NSUserdefaults and sometimes its crashing -

EDIT- This is from Crashlytics reporting- Anyone ca help now ?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001
 raw
0
libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_retain + 17
1
TestApp 
IBGSession.m line 339
-[IBGSession getViewHierarchy:fromParent:withMaxDepth:]
2
TestApp 
IBGSession.m line 320
-[IBGSession getViewHierarchy:fromParent:]
3
TestApp 
IBGSession.m line 256
-[IBGSession addAction:to:from:]
4
TestApp 
IBGSession.m line 39
-[UIApplication(IBGApplication) IBGSendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
5
UIKit   
-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 38
6
UIKit   
-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 46
7
UIKit   
-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
8
UIKit   
-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 594
9
UIKit   
_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5528
10   CoreFoundation 
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
16   UIKit  
UIApplicationMain + 1136
17
TestApp 
main.m line 16
main
```

Comment: put breakpoints and find out actual line of code, where crash happens. Then post code block here.

Comment: Did you import Mapkit and any needed frameworks?

Comment: It would be good to see the rest of the stack.  But it smells like a garden-variety storage error, due, no doubt, to messing up reference counting somehow.  First run Analyzer and fix everything it finds (and also, of course, fix -- or at least "understand" -- any other warnings in your code).  If you still have a problem you'll have to use some of the other tools.

Comment: Thanks all, I will check with other tools.